# Python URL decoding?

Tags: javascript, python

In javascript I do the following:

```
encodeURIComponent(comments)
```

while in Python i do the following:

```
urllib2.unquote(comments)
```

For some reason, when I do the following:

```
encodedURIComponents('ø')
```

I get `%C3%B8`, but when I decode

```
urllib2.unquote('%C3%B8')
```

I get `Ã¸` instead of `ø`, which is the original character.

What gives?

I'm on a platform that uses jQuery on client side, and Python/Django server side.

Comment: The reason you're seeing this is that one side is using UTF-8, the other is using Latin-1. This is why you should never just use the default encodings and cross your fingers; if you have any non-ASCII characters, keep them in `unicode` strings internally, and encode and decode strings as appropriate at each boundary. (Python 3 makes this easier by giving you an error instead of mojibake when you get it wrong.)

Comment: The form on client side types in, I'm assuming UTF-8, while python/django uses unicode? I'm on Python 2.x.

Comment: Web forms have a way to specify the charset in each direction (in the HTTP headers, or the response body), and default to Latin-1. Python 2 has a way to encode and decode between `str` and `unicode`, and if you just use `str` you're dealing with bytes whose meaning is unspecified. (See what `sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns.) So get the charset the form uses, and decode the string into unicode to work with; when sending it back, encode to UTF-8 and set the charset (or, better, let Django take care of it, in case the browser sends an `Accept-Charset` for some reason).

Answer (score 7):

Simply try to decode it:

```
urllib2.unquote('%C3%B8').decode('utf-8')   # --> 'ø'
```

Comment: note: it is actually [`urllib.unquote()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib#urllib.unquote)

Comment: If I do that, I get `u'\xf8'`...?

Comment: @user1886965: `u'\xf8'` is the exact same string as `u'ø'`, because `ø` is the 248th Unicode character.

Comment: @abarnert: So how do I prepare it for web viewing?

Comment: @user1886965: I'm not sure what you mean by that. I'm believe Django lets you pass `unicode` strings everywhere, and does any conversions necessary for talking to the browser/client, and to the database, and the log files, etc., so you don't need to do anything. I'm not sure why you ever need the line `urllib.unquote('%C3%B8')` in your code, so if there's a problem, and VisioN's answer doesn't solve it, maybe explain your actual use case?

Comment: My use case is as follows: 
1. I have multiple textarea (quantity is unspecified), that user enters comments with spaces/newlines 
2. I do some ajax magic, and do URL encode to all the textarea so I can compress it into ONE hidden field before submission
3. I receive in django the form, look in the hidden field for my data
4. I output the data onto a receipt printed in HTML

The problem I was trying to resolve was newlines screwed up the javascript so it wouldn't stuff the comments into the hidden text field and hence the url encoding.

Is this a bad way of resolving this?

Comment: @abarnert
By the way, I don't see VisioNs answer? Supposedly he/she edited something.

Comment: I forgot to mention that when I say compress, I mean create a json and stick it in the hidden field.

Comment: @user1886965: The answer you're replying to in these comments _is_ VisioN's answer. Anyway, it sounds like you've got too many layers of encoding here—a URL-encoded field that's actually a JSON-encoded object that holds URL-encoded fields? If there's a mismatch between the two sides with something that complex, it's going to be hard for anyone to guess where the mismatch is, if you don't show us the actual code. It is clear that the problem is that somewhere, at least in your example code, you're trying to interpret UTF-8 as Latin-1; as to where that happens in your real code, who knows?

Comment: Ah, I see gotcha. The process is actually as follows: 1. take the comments and url encode it 2. manually create a json from the url encoded comment using javascript 3. stick it in the hidden field using javascript 4. submit it 5. on server, retrieve the json 6. convert the json to dictionary (using the json.loads() function) 7. this is then outputted using "print" function.